# Forward module unable to send e-mails

Tags: email

I am new in using drupal and have stuck at a point which I am not able to figure out where am I going wrong...

I need to make "Recommend a friend" application in my site. For that Can anyone suggest me the best modules which I can use for this purpose.

I have found many related modules for this but unfortunately those are not compatible with Drupal 7 such as:
Tell a friend
Tell a friend node

Is there any alternative module which I can use for "Recommend a friend" app where I can send a mail to multiple recipients?

For the meanwhile, I am using "Forward" module which e-mails the entire page. I have installed it completely but I am not able to send any mails.
Before that I have used "Webform" module and for that i even installed SMTP and configured it properly and also I am able to send e-mails from this module.
I am not able to identify where I am going wrong.. Is there anything else which i need to configure for "Forward" module so as to send e-mails properly?

I am getting the following error:
Unable to send e-mail. Contact the site administrator if the problem persists.

Comment: I am not even getting any error for this issue.
After clicking on "Send Message" to send an email it just redirects to the front page.Not even getting any error and in "Recent Log Entries" nothing has changed.No entries I could found in that regarding mail cancellation or anything like that.